# Office add-in without SSL

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js

I have created a manifest for a Word add-in that refers to a web page that is not secured by https. I get errors in the Word host and can tell Word to temporarily accept this but cannot find how to tell it to ignore the warning on every launch.

Comment: Good question I'm following the instructions posted by MS and run into the same issue https://dev.office.com/getting-started/addins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will actually be an issue in the Online versions of Office because the apps themselves are always https, and thus generate mixed content (both http and https) if your app isn't.

Also, it is generally a bad idea to have an unsecured add-in. You're allowing an application to read the documents you're working on, without https you'd never know if you're actually allowing a 'fake add-in' to read all your data and save it somewhere else.

Lastly, the Office store does not allow non-https add-ins at all, so if you're planning in distributing your app through the store you will definitely need SSL.

Answer (score -1):

What are the error that you get in Wordhost? Word does normally not complain when a http:// address is used in a taskpane. Do you maybe have mixed content in the website?

Comment: Questions aren't answer's